# Is it possible to use 8 and 16 bit pointers on modern machines?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2013

See title. I'm considering building a "no-collision" hash-table - yes, I know it sounds dumb but I want to try it. I would have to have an enormous array of pointers to a relatively small patch of memory which would also consist of just pointers to the actual searchable data.

So I want the actual enormous array of hash keys to take up as little memory as possible, which is why 16 bit pointers would be nice. That would give me a 64 kb memory space to reference. Or even have a system of tiny tables referring small 256 byte sections of memory arranged in some cunning system.

Are less-than-32-bit pointers in any way possible in Visual C++ running on Windows 7? Using assembler, perhaps?

Comment: Why not using `16`-bit indexes in an 64 kB array?

Comment: You can use one pointer, and use pointer arithmetic. However, using an array is a much nicer way of doing this (and essentially the same thing)

Comment: Thanks. A pointer would've been more convenient to use, but yeah, array indexes do the same thing, which is like, DUH :))))

Comment: You can use 16-bit index into a 64k byte array or a 64k any type array.  With proper manipulation, you could even index into 64k-**bits**.

Comment: If you want to use pointers instead of indices, then you could use 16 bit offsets from a base pointer to an array.

Comment: [x32-abi](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/) is a new ABI to use 32-bit pointers on 64-bit systems, which is "similar" to your idea in some aspects. But for small amount like 8 or 16-bits then array index is a much easier solution